# Pandas csv parser not working properly when it encounters `"`

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding, csv-parser

Problem statement:

Initially what I had

> I have a CSV file with the below records:-
>
> data.csv:-

> ```
>  id,age,name
>  3500300026,23,"rahul"
>  3500300163,45,"sunita"
>  3500320786,12,"patrick"
>  3500321074,41,"Viper"
>  3500321107,54,"Dawn Breaker"
> ```

> When I tried to run script.py on this with encoding 'ISO-8859-1', it's running fine

> ```
> # script.py
> import pandas as pd
> test_data2=pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
> print(test_data2)
> ```

> [image: Result1]

---

Now what I have:-

> But when I got a feed of the same file with `"` at the front of every record, the parser behaved awkwardly. After the data change, new records looks like below:-

> ```
> id,age,name
> "3500300026,23,"rahul"
> "3500300163,45,"sunita"
> "3500320786,12,"patrick"
> "3500321074,41,"Viper"
> "3500321107,54,"Dawn Breaker"
> ```

> And after running the same script (script.py) for this new data file, I am getting the below result

> [image: Result2]

Character `"` comes under ISO-8859-1 Character Set only so this can't be an issue anyway. It should be the parser, can't really get it why isn't the parser only focusing on `,` which I specifically passed as a separator to read_csv().

References: [ISO-8859-1 Character set](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp)

I am curious to know the reason why pandas was not able to parse it properly or does it has any special connection with `"`.

Comment: It's not a valid csv file with the unmatched `"` at the beginning of each line.  This "feed" is broken.  This isn't anything to do with character encoding. Whoever provides that feed, inquire of them how to get valid csv data.

Comment: the issue is that there is a starting `"`, but there does not seem to be an ending `"`. what is the starting quote there for? Is it part of the id? if `"` is part of the field & also used as the quote character, then it must be escaped (which does not appear to have happened). pandas is behaving properly, your csv data file is not.

Comment: Thanks, @O.Jones, and @Haleenmur for addressing my problem. I can see the data is corrupted, but we have some fields in which even if `"` ( double quotes ) comes, it doesn't matter, it expects the parser to only parse on `,` and not check for anything.

Comment: As I have explicitly mentioned in the code `,` as the separator, so I don't expect `"` to create any issue with my data as long as my encoding character set for every value

Answer (score 1):

You can tell pandas that you don't want double quotes to be treated specially by adding an argument to read_csv:

```
  test_data2=pd.read_csv('data.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

to `read_csv()`. The output will be:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
            id  age            name
0  "3500300026   23         "rahul"
1  "3500300163   45        "sunita"
2  "3500320786   12       "patrick"
3  "3500321074   41         "Viper"
4  "3500321107   54  "Dawn Breaker"
```

parsing only on the comma.

Comment: Where are you using the `quoting` variable. can you please point me there

Comment: You forgot to mention that csv is a library to import but nps . Thanks a lot for your help :)